# How to select elements from an array based on the indices of another array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to filter by index:

```
a = [10,20,30,40]
b = [1,3]
a.filter((x,i) => b.includes(i))
// [20, 40]
```

Comment: @Redu, this would only work for sequential chunks

Comment: Sorry, my code had a mistake. I've updated the question

Comment: You have changed the question so now you have to do `b.map(i => a[i])` assuming `b` always carries indices mapping on some item in `a`

Comment: @Redu got it. Yes, that's better than what I was doing. I thought there might be something like `a.select(b)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another way would be `b.map(aIndex => a[aIndex])`. If `b` is shorter than `a` this could also be faster. However if there are indexes in `b` that do not belong in `a`, you would end up with `undefined` "holes" in the array.

**EDIT**

Looking a bit into `Array.includes`, looks like it will run in *O(n)* for unsorted arrays.
If we say `A = a.length` and `B = b.length`, your solution from the question should run in *O(A * B)*.
The second solution (with map) will run in  *O(B)*. To fix the `undefined` holes, you could add a `.filter(element => typeof element !== 'undefined')`.
The final solution would then be `b.map(i => a[i]).filter(e => typeof e !== 'undefined')`. This now runs in *O(2 * B)*, which should still be better than *O(A * B)*.

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is just great. `map` is a great solution too.

For the record, you could use a `for...of` loop, but it becomes much more complex for nothing...

```js
let a = [10, 20, 30, 40],
    b = [1, 3];

let res = [];
for (const entry of a.entries()) {
  if (b.includes(entry[0])) {
    res.push(entry[1]);
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

This (and more) can be done with Lodash's [`at`](https://lodash.com/docs/#at) function:

```
_.at([10, 20, 30, 40], [1, 3]) // [20, 40]
_.at(['a', 'b'], [0, 1, 1, 0]) // ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```